# Notice: Undefined index

Tags: php, html

**Não sei porque ta dando esse erro, já revisei tudo.**

Notice: Undefined index: primeiroNome in C:\xampp\htdocs\projeto\registro.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined index: sobrenome in C:\xampp\htdocs\projeto\registro.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined index: matricula in C:\xampp\htdocs\projeto\registro.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\projeto\registro.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined index: senha in C:\xampp\htdocs\projeto\registro.php on line 18

```
<?php 

    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $connection = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=*****', $username );

    $query = "INSERT INTO usuario (nome, sobrenome, matricula, email, senha) 
          VALUES (:nome, :sobrenome, :matricula, :email, :senha)";

    $statement = $connection->prepare($query);


    $valores = array();
    $valores[':nome'] = $_POST['primeiroNome'];
    $valores[':sobrenome'] = $_POST['sobrenome'];
    $valores[':matricula'] = $_POST['matricula'];
    $valores[':email'] = $_POST['email'];
    $valores[':senha'] = $_POST['senha'];





    $result = $statement->execute($valores);




    ?>
```

**Esta ai o meu form**

```
<form  method="POST" action ="" name="for">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="form-row">
                     <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="primeiroNome">Primeiro nome</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="primeiroNome" name="primeiroNome" placeholder="Digite seu primeiro nome">
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="Sobrenome">Sobrenome</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Sobrenome" name="sobrenome" placeholder="Digite seu Sobrenome">
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-6" id="matricula">
                  <label for="primeiroNome">Matrícula</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="matricula" placeholder="Digite sua matrícula">
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="email">E-mail</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Digite seu email">
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="form-row">
                     <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="senha">Senha</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="senha" name="senha" placeholder="Digite sua senha">
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="confirmaSenha">confirmar senha</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmaSenha" name="confirmaSenha" placeholder="Confirme sua senha">
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div>
                  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="registro.php" value="Registra-se"/>
               </div>
               <div class="text-center">
                  <a href="#" class="d-block small mt-3">Esqueceu sua senha?</a>
                  <a href="#" class="d-block small mt-3">Login?</a>
               </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: Você já estudou o protocolo HTTP, que é utilizado na Web? Existe diferenças entre você acessar uma página pelo método GET e pelo POST. Você está tentando acessar dados vindos em uma requisição POST quando ela é GET.

Comment: Seu formulário é exibido e tratado na mesma página? ( `action =""` ) Se sim, deveria então adicionar um `isset`, senão vai dar erro na primeira vez que abrir a página: `$valores[':nome'] = $_POST['primeiroNome'];` ficaria ` $valores[':nome'] = (isset($_POST['primeiroNome']) ? $_POST['primeiroNome'] : ''); ` ou, caso use PHP 7+, assim: `$valores[':nome'] = ($_POST['primeiroNome'] ?? '');`. Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Traduzindo o que disse o @AndersonCarlosWoss, caso não tenha ficado claro: quando você carrega a página para preencher o formulário, não tem nada recebido via POST. E todo o seu código PHP considera que sempre haverá dados recebidos via POST, o que só acontece quando o formulário é submetido. Em resumo, você precisa verificar se algo foi postado antes de executar o trecho de PHP mostrado.

Comment: Obrigado, ajudou bastante, Resolveu meu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema ocorre porque você coloca o atributo `href` no input de submit e não coloca o **registro.php** na `action` do form. Remova o atributo adicione a `action` e tente novamente. Deixo abaixo o seu HTML editado.

```
<form method="POST" action="registro.php" name="for">
           <div class="form-group">
              <div class="form-row">
                 <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label for="primeiroNome">Primeiro nome</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="primeiroNome" name="primeiroNome" placeholder="Digite seu primeiro nome">
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label for="Sobrenome">Sobrenome</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Sobrenome" name="sobrenome" placeholder="Digite seu Sobrenome">
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-6" id="matricula">
              <label for="primeiroNome">Matrícula</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="matricula" placeholder="Digite sua matrícula">
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">E-mail</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Digite seu email">
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
              <div class="form-row">
                 <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label for="senha">Senha</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="senha" name="senha" placeholder="Digite sua senha">
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label for="confirmaSenha">confirmar senha</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmaSenha" name="confirmaSenha" placeholder="Confirme sua senha">
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           <div>
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Registra-se"/>
           </div>
           <div class="text-center">
              <a href="#" class="d-block small mt-3">Esqueceu sua senha?</a>
              <a href="#" class="d-block small mt-3">Login?</a>
           </div>
        </form>
```